# $f(x)=\frac{\sin 3x}{\sin x}$ is decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, derivatives

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin 3x}{\sin x}$. How to prove that $f(x)$ is decreasing on $(0,\frac{\pi}{3})$?

I tried using the derivative $f'$ but didn't get $f'<0$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Albert, I tried with using derivatives but it doesn't gave any result.

Comment: Did you use trigonometric relations in your computations?

Comment: @Albert, What kind? Can you show proof? It would be great!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** Since $\sin 3x = -4\sin^3x+3\sin x$, the function is $-4\sin^2x+3$.

Without even taking derivatives, consider where $\sin x$ is increasing. What does that imply for $-\sin^2x$?

Answer (score 1):

Using

$$\begin{align}
\sin(a+b)&=\sin{a}\cos{b}+\cos{a}\sin{b}\\
\sin{2a}&=2\sin{a}\cos{a}\\
\cos{2a}&=2\cos^2{a}-1
\end{align}$$

one gets:

$$\sin{3x}=2\sin{x}\cos^2{x}+\sin{x}(2\cos^2{x}-1)$$

And this means $f(x)=4\cos^2{x}-1$ and

$$f'(x)=-8\cos{x}\sin{x}=-4\sin{2x}$$

negative on the given interval.

Comment: You might be meaning $f(x)=4\cos^2x-1$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin x} =\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\sin(2x)\cos x + \sin x \cos(2x)}{\sin x} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{2 \sin x \cos^2 x + \sin x \cos^2 x - \sin^3 x}{\sin x}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} ( 2\cos^2 x + \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x )= \frac{d}{dx} (4\cos^2 x - 1) =4 (2\cos x (-\sin x)) = -4\sin(2x)$$

I used the $\sin(a+b)$ formula in the first equality, with $a=x$, $b=2x$.
Then I just used the duplication formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$ and basic algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Putting $y = \frac{\sin (3x)}{\sin(x)}$ you have $\frac{d y}{d x} =  \frac{3 \sin(x) \cos(3x) - \sin(3x) \cos(x) }{\sin^2 x}$ [Please check this!]. The denominator is always non vanishing and positive on the region $ (0, \frac{\pi}{3}]$. What can you say about the numerator, $3 \sin(x) \cos(3x) - \sin(3x) \cos(x)$? In particular can you simplify the numerator? Though (with the correct mathematics put in! not so obvious ... apologies, may be able to go along this route if use results from the other answers).

Comment: Could you check again your derivative, the numerator should be $3\sin(x)\cos(3x)−\sin(3x)\cos(x)$, there is no common factor $3$ to extract.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$f(x)=\frac{\sin 3x}{\sin x}=\frac{3\sin x-4\sin^3x}{\sin x}=3-4\sin^2 x$$ $$f'(x)=-8\sin x\cos x=-4\sin(2x)\tag 1$$

Now, for given interval $0<x<\frac{\pi}{3}$, consider $$0<x\iff $$ $$\sin 0<\sin (2x)\iff $$ $$0<\sin(2x)\iff $$ $$-4\sin(2x)<0$$

From (1) we have, $f'(x)=-4\sin 2x<0$ hence $f(x)=\frac{\sin 3x}{\sin x}$ is decreasing on $\left(0, \frac{\pi}{3}\right)$

Comment: The part $0<x<\frac{\pi}{3}\iff\sin 0<\sin 2x<\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}$ is pure fantasy (and easily seen to be wrong).